# Can Visual Studio 2012/2013 professional make (managed/ c#) memory snapshots during profiling?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling

This is somewhat unclear.
We've been using JetBrains dotTrace Memory for memory profiling in C# before. As the latest version of it supports only .net 3.5 we are pretty stuck.

Can the visual studio profiler make memory snapshots at two distinct times and display the difference?

I am trying to pin down some memory leaks and I seem unable to get close to what causes them

I've read the post about profiling here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/04/04/net-memory-allocation-profiling-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx and it states you can make snapshots however I cannot find this feature in the professional version of Visual Studio.

Comment: a little off-topic, but the latest version of memory profiler by JetBrains called dotMemory and supports profiling .net 4.x applications